# Cannot resolve keyword 'blg' into field. Choices are: content, email, id, name, post, post_id

Tags: python, django, django-views

there are similar questions but still i am not able to figure out my mistake.. i am trying to make a comment system.. the comment model is working fine.. but when i try to edit my post detail view from this ..

```
   def detailview(request, id=None):
blg =  get_object_or_404(BlogPost, id=id)
context = {'blg': blg,
           'comments': comments,
           }
```

to this

```
  def detailview(request, id=None):
blg =  get_object_or_404(BlogPost, id=id)
comments = Comment.objects.filter(blg = blg).order_by('-id')
context = {'blg': blg,
           'comments': comments,
           }
```

i am getting this error

```
   Cannot resolve keyword 'blg' into field. Choices are: content, email, id, name, post, post_id
```

here are my other files...

models..

```
             class BlogPost(models.Model):


title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
writer = models.CharField(max_length=150,default='my dept')
category =models.CharField(max_length=150)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
post   = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
Date  = models.DateField( default=datetime.date.today)


def __str__(self):
    return self.title




      
   class Comment(models.Model):
       post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      name = models.CharField (max_length = 150)
      email = models.CharField (max_length = 150)
          content = models.TextField ()

          def __str__(self):
               return self.email
```

forms.py

```
        from django import forms

         from.models import Comment

         class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
                class Meta:
                 model = Comment
                 fields = ('content',)
```

views.py

```
            def detailview(request, id=None):
                blg =  get_object_or_404(BlogPost, id=id)
                comments = Comment.objects.filter(blg = blg).order_by('-id')
                context = {'blg': blg,
                           'comments': comments,
                          }
```

Comment: Isn't the error message clear?

Comment: @Selcuk when i am using `content`  instead of `blg` it is giving following error - `NameError at /blog/3/
name 'content' is not defined`

Comment: Why would you use `content`? How is it even relevant? You should use `Comment.objects.filter(post=blg)`.

Comment: hi @Selcuk thnkyou..  i got you..